# Context aware fzf command

Tags: plugin-fzf

I would like to have a file extension aware `:FZF` command, so that when I choose a file with enter from the fzf prompt, and that file has an extension that matches a list (say `(pdf|mp3|jpg)`), it opens the file with some external bash command (say `open`, I'm on mac), and otherwhise just opens it in vim buffer ar normal.

I have the following in my `.vimrc`

```
let g:fzf_action = {
  \ 'ctrl-t': 'tab split',
  \ 'ctrl-x': '!open',
  \ 'ctrl-v': 'vsplit', }
```

which lets me open files with an external program with `ctrl-x` from the prompts, but my brain can't handle this very well and I often press enter instead of `ctrl-x`. One single context aware command would be much better.

Comment: This sounds more like a enhancement request for fzf than a question about Vim.

Comment: @Ralf Maybe. I thought with a little bit of vimscript it aught not to be too difficult. That's why i posted here.

Comment: I saw a post somewhere recently about using filetype plugins to trigger specific commands (e.g. `!open %`, then `bdelete`, then `b #`) for filetypes like the ones you suggest. I’ll see if I can dig it up

Comment: https://vimways.org/2018/opening-non-vim-file-formats/

Comment: @Knoble That does indeed solve the problem. Seems like like a bit of a detour though to load a video as vim buffer before running it with an external program. This method also effectively changes the alternative # buffer (by opening the non textfile as a buffer, making that the # buffer, and then deleting it) which can be annoying.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble If you make that an answer ill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I read at [Vimways](https://vimways.org/2018/opening-non-vim-file-formats/), I would do something like this:

First, we need filetype-detection working, so for every filetype you need, in `~/.vim/ftdetect/<filetype>.vim`, put

```
autocommand BufRead,BufNewFile *.<ext>[,*.<ext>] set filetype=<filetype>
```

(The example in the article uses `video` as a filetype, with a plethora of extensions matching.)

Next, we must execute the appropriate actions, so in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` you'll want to

```
silent execute "!<external commands to view the file>" | buffer# | bdelete# | redraw! | syntax on
```

If, like me, you prefer to reorganize the code a bit:

```
function! s:command() abort
  " execute the external viewing command
endfunction

function! s:nextfile() abort
  buffer #
  bdelete #
  redraw!
  " this may or may not be necessary...
  " it might also be 'syntax enable' or even just 'edit'
  syntax on
endfunction

silent call s:command()
silent call s:nextfile()
```

Comment: One could also use `silent!`, though in this case I may want error messages